# pandas reset_index() to reset index but without any change in order of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I use **`set_index()`** to set a multi-index using some of the columns in my data frame,
then I use `reset_index()`; the index is reset but order of columns is changed, but I want **only the index to be reset but the columns to keep the existing order**:

**Existing order of columns**: (X,A,Y,Z,B,C)

```
df.set_index(['A','B','C'],inplace=True)

df.reset_index()
# then order of columns in dataframe gets changed to A,B,C,X,Y,Z....
```

but I want my columns to keep the existing order (X,A,Y,Z,B,C) after `reset_index()`.

How to do this in pandas?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE] example of your dataframe.

Comment: `df.set_index(keys)` interprets `keys` as a list containing an arbitrary combination of column keys and arrays. It makes ['A','B','C'] a multiindex. The remaining columns are 'X','Y','Z'.

Answer (score 0):

First is necessary create another DataFrame for avoid overwrite original columns and then in last step use `reindex`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['A','B','C'])

df1 = df1.reset_index().reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Or create new variable for original columns names:

```
cols = df.columns
df.set_index(['A','B','C'],inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index().reindex(cols, axis=1)
```